# Measuring/monitoring Unbound Resolver Performance

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, unbound

I am running Unbound resolver on FreeBSD, and i am looking for a solution to measure  its performance.sometimes there are some delays in regard of resolving domain names,and my customers are complaining. 
Also using Zabbix monitoring system to monitor QPS.But is there any solution to monitor the performance of unbound itself?
i have come-up to measure this delay via Cisco SLA, but i am looking for non-Cisco based solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could user [SmokePing](https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/index.en.html) with [DNS probe](https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/DNS.en.html):